# c++ passing objects between classes

Tags: c++, class, error-handling, constructor

I am learning c++ classes and in my course I need to create a book store using which contains "book", "author" and "Store" classes.

I'm not quite sure how to interact between classes when it comes down to extract the Author's name within the Book class.

When I run the below piece of code in Xcode I am notified of the following error on the Oeuvre's class' contructor: Expected '(' or '{'

**UDPATE  22-Nov-2016**
I have updated the code with what I have done so far.

First, I have issue when I try to display the author's name from the Book_copy class. I simply don't know how to do it.

I've put author.getName() just for now, but I know it won't work.

The second issue is an errors that comes with the disable Author copy constructors and the Book constructor. ???

Third problem, assuming that the above are fixed, it would not entirely follow the instruction I received to build this program.

The Book class must be characterized by: a string title, a constant reference to its author, and another string for the language it was written in.

That's where I got screwed in the first place trying to use a const reference to the author...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Author{
private:
    string name;
    bool award;

public:
    Author(string name, bool award=false) : name(name), award(award) {}
    const string getName(){ return name; }
    const bool getAward() { return award; }
    Author(Author const&) = delete;
};

class Book{
private:
    string title;
    Author &author;
    string language;

public:
    Book(string title, Author author, string language) : title(title), author(author), language(language) {}
    const string getTitle() { return title; }
    string getAuthor() { return author.getName(); }
    const string getLanguage() { return language; }
    void display_book() { cout << title <<  author.getName() << endl; }
    ~Book() { cout << title << author.getName() <<  endl;}
    Book(Book const&) = delete;
};

class Book_copy{
private:
    Book &book;

public:
    Book_copy(Book &nuovo) : book(nuovo) {
        cout  <<  book.getTitle() <<  author.getName() << endl;
    }
    /*** Copy constructor ***/
   // Book_copy(Book_copy const& dupli) 

    ~Book_copy () {
        cout << book.getTitle() <<  author.getName()  << endl;
    }

    const Book &getBook() const { return book; }
    void display_book() { cout <<  book.getTitle() <<  author.getName() <<  endl; }
};

class Library{
private:
    vector <Book_copy*> bibil;
    string name;

public:
    Library(string name) : name(name){
        cout << name << " is open" << endl;
    }
    const string &getName() { return name; }

    void store(Book_copy const &livre, unsigned int qty = 1) {
        for(unsigned int i(0); i < qty; i++){
            // This is where I need to store the number of book copy in the library...
        }
    }


    ~Library() {
        cout <<  name << " is closing down" << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Author a1("Victor Hugo"),
    a2("Stephen King"),
    a3("Raymond Queneau", true);


    Book o1("Les Misérables", a1, "french" );
    Book o2("Carrie", a2, "english" );

    Library biblio("whatever");
    biblio.store(o1);
    biblio.store(o2, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

There are probably some concepts I haven't fully understood and that's why I am creating those issues.

Please enlighten me.

**UPDATE 29-Nov-2016**

Nobody? I'am going circle here. Every time I get something to work, something else does work anymore...   :(
The code below nearly works, except that it seems the Bibiliotheque vector is empty.
There are too many lines and some are totally useless, I am going back and forth trying different thing to make it work...

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Auteur{
    private:
        string nom;
        bool prix;

    public:
        Auteur(string nom="", bool prix=false)
        : nom(nom), prix(prix) {}

        string getNom() { return nom; }
        bool getPrix() { return prix; }
        Auteur(Auteur const&) = delete;
    };

    class Oeuvre{
    private:
        string titre;
        Auteur &auteur;
        string langue;

    public:
        Oeuvre(string titre, Auteur &auteur, string langue)
        : titre(titre), auteur(auteur), langue(langue) {}

        const string getTitre() { return titre; }
        string getAuteur() const { return auteur.getNom(); }
        const Auteur &getAut() const { return auteur; }
        string getLangue() { return langue; }
        void affiche() const { cout<<"Affiche "<<titre<<auteur.getNom()<<langue << endl; }
        ~Oeuvre() { cout<<"Destroyed "<<titre<<auteur.getNom()<<langue<< endl; }
        Oeuvre(Oeuvre const&) = delete;
    };

    class Examplaire{
    private:
        Oeuvre &oeuvre;

    public:
        Examplaire(Oeuvre &nuovo)
        : oeuvre(nuovo){ cout<<"New "<<oeuvre.getTitre()<<oeuvre.getAuteur()<<oeuvre.getLangue() << endl; }

        Examplaire(Examplaire const& copie)
        : oeuvre(copie.oeuvre){ cout<<"Copy "<<oeuvre.getTitre()<<oeuvre.getAuteur()<<oeuvre.getLangue() << endl; }

        const Oeuvre &getOeuvre() const { return oeuvre; }
        string getTitre() { return //TODO need to return title
            oeuvre.getTitre();
        }
        string getLangue() { return "";
    //        oeuvre.getLangue(); // crashes!! TODO need to return language
        }

        void affiche() { cout<<"Affiche "<< oeuvre.getTitre()<<oeuvre.getAuteur()<<oeuvre.getLangue();
        }
    };

    class Bibliotheque{
    private:
        vector <Examplaire*> bibil;
        string name;

    public:
        Bibliotheque(string name) : name(name){
            cout << "La bibliothèque " << name << " est ouverte !" << endl;
        }

        const string &getNom() { return name; }

        void stocker(Oeuvre & livre, unsigned int qty = 1) {
            for(int i(0); i < qty; i++){
                Examplaire temp = livre;
                bibil.push_back(&temp);
            }
        }

        const void lister_exemplaires(string langue = "none") const {
            for(auto & book : bibil){
                if((book->getLangue() == langue))
                    cout << book->getTitre() << endl;
                // TODO display books in a chosen language or all if none
            }
        }
        int compter_exemplaires(Oeuvre &livre) const{
            int compt = 0;
            for(auto * book : bibil){
                //  TODO display how many copy of livre
                if(book->getTitre() == livre.getTitre())
                    compt++;
            }
            return compt;
        }

        void afficher_auteurs(bool prix = false) const{
            for(auto * book : bibil){
                //  TODO display auteur names based on prix true or false
            }
        }

        ~Bibliotheque() {
            cout << "La bibliothèque " << name << " ferme ses portes,"<< endl;
            cout << "et détruit ses exemplaires :" << endl;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Auteur a1("Victor Hugo"),
        a2("Alexandre Dumas"),
        a3("Raymond Queneau", true);

        Oeuvre o1("Les Misérables "           , a1, " français" ),
        o2("L'Homme qui rit "          , a1, " français" ),
        o3("Le Comte de Monte-Cristo " , a2, " français" ),
        o4("Zazie dans le métro "      , a3, " français" ),
        o5("The Count of Monte-Cristo ", a2, " anglais" );

        Bibliotheque biblio("public");
        biblio.stocker(o1, 2);
        biblio.stocker(o2);
        biblio.stocker(o3, 3);
        biblio.stocker(o4);
        biblio.stocker(o5);

        cout << "The library contains :"<< endl;
        biblio.lister_exemplaires();

        cout << "The books is english are :" << endl;
        biblio.lister_exemplaires("anglais");

        cout << "Award authors are:" << endl;
        biblio.afficher_auteurs(true);

        cout << biblio.compter_exemplaires(o3)<< " cpoy of Monte christo (should be 3)"<<endl;

        cout << "o4 title is " << o4.getTitre()<< "(should be Zazie) :" << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You misspelled `Author`'s constructor's name.

Comment: the constructor name should match the class name.Also one object holding a reference to another object, thats more of a design question...sort of composition vs aggregation.

Comment: Thanks. The classes, attributes, constructor and so forth were in a different language, I translated them to give a bit of context. I forgot that one.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not compiling because you did not initialize private reference member to Author class. Correct your initialization list.

```
Book(string title, const Author &author, string language) 
    : title(title), author(author), language(language) {}
```

Comment: I have tried this way but it brings another issue when I try to output the content on the terminal.   

**ror: passing 'const Author' as 'this' argument of 'const string Author::getName()' discards qualifiers**  
_The following is the method I need in the Book class :_ '
void display() const { cout <<  title << ", " << Author.getName() << ", en " << language << endl; }'

Answer (score 0):

with the book class having `Author &author` private it is not necessarily required as the manipulation of the variable is restricted with it being private. For the error where you call `author.getName()` I am pretty sure that is the error as where you call it it is a ctor-initialization which is where you set variables in your class and since the variable at that position is a pointer and you call `getName()` which returns a std::string there is a mismatch. I think you are also going to get an error as you make the `const Author &author` point to a space in memory but you don't actually tell it where to point. It should be something like `const Author &author = nullptr;`

Side note: From what I can see you are using `using namespace std`. AT NO POINT SHOULD YOU EVER DO THAT. when you use that line you are opening yourself up to a ton of errors and headaches. If for some reason you want to make it easier you can write the line `using std::string` at the top of your header or source file. Then you can use it the same way you are using it now.

Comment: I changed the constructor with `Book(string title, const Author &author, string language) 
    : title(title), author(author), language(language) {}` in the Book class but now I also need the following method to output the content on the terminal. `void display() const { cout << title << ", " << Author.getName() << ", en " << language << endl; }` That creates another error message _error: passing 'const Auteur' as 'this' argument of 'const string Auteur::getNom()' discards qualifiers_

Comment: I think it might have to do with your `getName()`. there really is no reason for that to be constant as you are not returning a reference or pointer. If that is not the issue it might be the `const` on the display as again that is not really needed. If for some reason neither of those are not the problem then I would get rid of the const on the `author` variable as it is not needed/is not actually constant. also you need to call the method in display as `author.getName()` but I assume that is an error from translating.